# How is changing a js file to php using AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js make a web app insecure?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, security

I want to execute some php code inside a javascript file in codeigniter using

.htaccess

```
<Directory /path/>
<Files file.js>
    AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js
</Files>
```

and in my javascript file

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript', true)
```

I have read from the codeigniter forums that executing php inside a .js file may make my web application insecure but i don't understand why this is.

How can a client exploit the changes i made of being able to execute php in the js file?.

Comment: perhaps you should reference what you read.

Comment: Is that really necessary?It says pretty much what i've written.

Comment: it doesn't make it insecure, but **ANY** php warnings/errors that the code causes will get embedded in the JS and cause syntax errors at best. You have to make DAMN sure that whatever your PHP is doing produces valid javascript at the end of the line, otherwise the entire JS code block is terminated/blacklisted

Comment: Will that hold when i have display errors off and also expose php off?.

Comment: because its wrong, that's way